# How to handle "e-mail message cannot be sent" error

Tags: workflow, email, error-handling

I have a workflow that uses a SendEmail activity, then moves on to some other work. If I get this error below (because the smtp server is down for some reason):

> The e-mail message cannot be sent. 
>   Make sure the outgoing e-mail settings for the server are configured correctly.

I would like the workflow to terminate instead of continuing on. How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like outgoing email has not been configured in Central Administration.  You just need to setup your outgoing SMTP server settings.

EDIT

The accepted answer is actually in the comments below. Though, the above solution is something that should also be checked.

Comment: Here are the instructions: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263462.aspx

Comment: Actually, it was (and is) configured correctly. The ability for the sharepoint server to communicate with the SMTP server was disrupted for a period of time. I would like to be able to terminate the workflow if this happens again.

Comment: In fact, I went digging into the Sharepoint log: "Cannot connect to SMTP host ...". The "..." is the correct name of the SMTP server, it just wasn't able to get to it for a period of time.

Comment: You could install the SMTP service on the SharePoint server itself that forwards the mail to your main SMTP server.  Then configure SharePoint to use itself.  It will queue the mail until it can be emailed out.

Comment: Don't think there is anyway to actually terminate a designer workflow on this type of error.  Would need a VS workflow.

Comment: It actually is a VS workflow... using a SendEmail activity.

Comment: The SendEmail function returns a bool (true or false) as to whether or not it successfully sends the email.  Simply do an If statement on if it returns false.  Then throw an exception (throw new Exception("Blah");).

Comment: Thanks. I figured I'd have to go with that option. I was hoping for some solution where I could keep the SendEmail activity.

Comment: You can still use the function, just needs to be "bool success = SendEmail(...);"  And then you do "if(!success) { throw error... }"

Comment: Sorry but the OOTB SendEmail activity has been coded to swallow any error and just write an event to the history list. So your only option to catch that error would be to read through the log, but it's a lot easier to write a custom activity which uses `SPUtility.SendEmail` directly and reports any error.